# Best practice for Loading many files to local Documents Directory on iPad

Tags: ios, zip, ios5, unpack

I'm about to write an app for iPad2 to make website offline available.
Several Publications (consisting of one HTML, one Javascript an many PNG Files) need to be downloaded to the iPad for offline Viewing.

Is there a good unzip-class for iOS so that i could download a zip from server and unpack it to a subdirectory in Documents Folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compression doesn't matter, the `untar` algorithm is pretty easy to implement. Either you keep it as plain C, or you adapt it to objective-C.

Reference: http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/source/browse/trunk/contrib/untar.c?r=1143

Comment: The server is a linux system with a php application. Should be no big thing to tar instead of zipping files.

Comment: Yep, easy as pie. That's exactly what I'm doing in one of our apps — we're downloading a collection of PNG files which are already compressed by nature, so we chose TAR instead of ZIP. I've got a small Untarrer class that handles the job after downloading (it's been adapted from C to Obj-C to handle concurrent untars).

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/ looks like the right code for your needs.

Comment: If there are subdirectories in the Zip-file, does this lib handle them? Or do I need to extract them manually from the returned file names?

Comment: Yes and no. You can find the information about using folders within the getting started guide: http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/wiki/GettingStarted